# $resource relations in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The usual way of defining an isolated resource in AngularJS is:

```
angular.service('TheService', function($resource){
  return $resource('api/url');
});
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to write a model that relates to other models, such as an `Order` that has 1 or more `OrderItem`s. My first idea is this:

1. Create the `OrderService` and `OrderItemService` as independent resource models
2. Write a controller that queries the `OrderService` and watches the result array
3. When the result array changes, query the `OrderItemService` for all of the item IDs and decorate the `order` object with extended information as it comes in

That seems a bit messy. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: it raises "TypeError: angular.service is not a function"

Comment: IIRC, I asked this when Angular was pre-1.0. The API has likely changed since then.

Comment: No problem, I created an updated question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11038425/599991

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
angular.service('OrderItem', function($resource) {
  return $resource('api/url/orderItem');
});

angular.service('Order', function($resource, OrderItem) {
  var Order = $resource('api/url/order');

  Order.prototype.items = function(callback) {
    return order.query({orderId: this.id}, callback);
  }
  return Order
});
```

Would something like above solve your problem? You would then use it as

```
var order, items;

Order.get({id: 123}, function(o) {
  order = o;
  o.items(function(is) { items = is; });
});
```

Angular's $resource does not understand relationships. It is something we would like to change in post 1.0.

I don't think you should put the data on the order directly, since it is not part of it, and you will have issues persisting the order since it will now have the items object as well.

Comment: We're doing a kind of CQRS, so the Order data is read-only anyway. Thanks!

Comment: I think the items function should use `OrderItem` instead of `order`.

Comment: It seems to be obsolete.
How can we use it with factories?

Comment: TypeError: angular.service is not a function

Comment: When you change this, will you make it look for rel's in the header? Or in the body? Are we talking about intelligently consuming actual hypermedia APIs? because that would be huge.